# what conditions on a function $P$ guarantee $P$ is a "good approximation of order $n$ of a function $f$"?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, functions

if [some condition about the derivatives of $f$ and $P$ at $0$], then $P$ is a good approximation of order $n$ for $f$ near $x=0$

Let $f$ be a function and we want to approximate $f$ using a different function $P$ near $x=0$. The error of approximation is $E(x)=f(x)-P(x)$. If the approximation is going to be any good, we want  $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}E(x)=0$. In fact, we want $E(x)$ approaches $0$ fast as $x\rightarrow 0$

Definition for $good \ approximation$: we say that $P$ is a good approximation of order $n$ for $f$ near $x=0$ when $E(x)$ approaches $0$ faster than $h_n(x)=x^n$.

Definition for $approach\ 0\ faster$: Assume $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)=0$. We say $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)$ approaches $0$ faster than $g(x)$, as $x\rightarrow 0$, when $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$.

In my opinion, to let $E(x)$ approaches $0$ faster than $h_n(x)=x^n$, we need to have $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{E(x)}{x^n}=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-P(x)}{x^n}=0$. Then using L'Hospital's rule $n$ times, we have $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f^n(x)-P^n(x)}{n!}$. To make it $0$, we need either $f^n(x)=P^n(x)$ or $f^n(x)-P^n(x)$ has degree higher than or equal to $x$. But $P(x)$ is a function different from $f(x)$. Therefore, I think the condition should be "the $n$th derivative of $f$ and $P$ has difference with degree of $1$ or higher".

But I feel strange about my statement. Could someone help correct it?

Comment: Why degree 1? Note, e.g., that $\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{|x|}/n!=0$. Also, you say "Then using L'Hospital's rule $n$ times..." To do this, you need $(f(x)-P(x))\to0$, and $(f'(x)-P'(x))\to0$, and $(f''(x)-P''(x))\to0$, and so on.

Comment: The theorem is definitely incorrect with my statement. But I don't know a better way to revise it.

Comment: @CoolKid if $f$ is $n$ times differentiable at $0$, then there exists a polynomial which approximates $f$ at $0$ with order $n$ (just take the Taylor polynomial). The reverse is in general not true. In fact there exists non differentiable function which admits order $n$ approximation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. If we want the polynomial to have degree as small as possible, can we just use from the start to $n+1$th term of Taylor's polynomial?

Comment: @CoolKid the degree $n$ Taylor polynomial is a order $n$ approximation. You can prove it using l'hopital or epsilon-delta. Both by induction.